# What was Emiru doing during the 1 year timeskip?

Tags: nozoki-ana

In chapter 116 of *Nozoki Ana*, there's a 1 year timeskip.

Is there any explanation of what Emiru was doing during the timeskip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing official but my take on it:

Deep down she knew that she is still not able to run a relationship. Thus she decided to leave entirely. However, Kido kinda decided to gamble rather than losing her forever. He gave one year time period for her to improve her personality and think about all that happened. You could say "Well she can do that while being with Kido" however that's wrong. She is so obsessive about Kido and rotten inside thus being with her would defeat the entire purpose of "I want to be a better person."

In the end, it worked out.

Comment: I really think it like that, I don't want to think that Emiru done anything with the other guys. You know, after all Kido did wait for her for such a long time. Even Yuri-chan wants the D again.